How create a tiff image from dataframe with a grid python
I have a dataframe with a grid of 3 columns
utm N utm E Value
How can i create a tiff image using this grid ?
Data:
          E              N             value

0   754104.853089   7.105749e+06    -0.001245
1   755104.853089   7.105749e+06    -0.001168
2   756104.853089   7.105749e+06    -0.001071
3   757104.853089   7.105749e+06    -0.000931
4   758104.853089   7.105749e+06    -0.000827


You appear to have 5 equally spaced points on an East-West line. What sort of image are you hoping for? At best it will only be a line profile surely?

The first step is to read in your CSV, probably into a Pandas dataframe. Then to find the minimum and maximum latitude, the minimum and maximum longitude and the minimum and maximum value. Presuming you want a greyscale image, you would then make a new column that normalises your 'value' column to a range of 0..255 using norm = 255*(currentvalue-min)/(max-min). Now you're in a good place to put those values as pixels into a raster. See how far you can get.
